# How to extract date from a text field using TSQL for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I'm trying to extract date from a text field.  I'm using PADINDEX to do this. My results are very inconsistent.  Is there anyway I can do this through SQL.  I don't have an application to do this for me.  I am trying to get this for a report that is needed.

The text field has dates that are not always listed as MM/DD/YYYY   sometimes its listed as M/DD/YYYY.  Also,

Here is the query I am using:

```sql
select
substring(ar.finding_text,patindex('%[0-9]%/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',ar.finding_text),10)

FROM [ARKPPDB].[PowerPath].[dbo].[accession_2] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN acc_results ar on a.id = ar.acc_id
```

Comment: Honestly, this is not SQL Server's forté. Ideally fix your design, and store the date in it's own column to start with, and if you must parse this kind of thing, you are far better off doing it in a language that has *good* text manipulation tools.

Comment: Sample data and expected results *might* be useful here....

Comment: Side note: You state from a "text field" here. Firstly by "text" do you mean the data type `text`, or a string based data type (such as `varchar`)? If the former, `text` has been deprecated for ~17 years; you should not be using it any more. Secondly, tables don't have "fields", they have columns. Correct terminology is important.

Comment: I'll give you the same answer as I gave you on the other forum.  You REALLY need to provide some example strings, Asha.  You'd be amazed at what happens when you do.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Thank you all for your assistance.

```
select 
*,
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([Time Client 
Called], CHARINDEX('on',[Time Client Called]), 15),13))) is null, null, 
LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([Time Client Called], CHARINDEX('on',[Time 
Client Called]), 15),13)))), 'a', ''),'t','')))  as "Date Client Called",

IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([Time Client Called], CHARINDEX('at',[Time 
Client Called]), 11),8))) is null, null, LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([Time 
Client Called], CHARINDEX('at',[Time Client Called]), 11),8))))  as "Time 
Called"

into #tmpCalls
FROM #tmpPattern
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a pattern "priority" like this:

```
DECLARE @Patterns TABLE(Pattern VARCHAR(100),PatternLength INT)

INSERT INTO @Patterns(Pattern, PatternLength)
VALUES('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',19),
    ('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',18),
    ('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',18),
    ('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',17),
    ('%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',18),
    ('%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',17),
    ('%[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',17),
    ('%[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%',16)

SELECT IIF(pat1.Pattern is null or LEN(replace(upper(ar.finding_text),' AT ',' ')) < patindex(pat1.Pattern,replace(upper(ar.finding_text),' AT ',' '))+pat1.PatternLength, null,substring(replace(UPPER(ar.finding_text),' AT ',' '),patindex(pat1.Pattern,replace(upper(ar.finding_text),' AT ',' ')),pat1.PatternLength))
FROM [ARKPPDB].[PowerPath].[dbo].[accession_2] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN acc_results ar on a.id = ar.acc_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Patterns pat1 on patindex(pat1.Pattern,replace(upper(ar.finding_text),' AT ',' ')) > 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Patterns pat2 on patindex(pat2.Pattern,replace(upper(ar.finding_text),' AT ',' ')) > 0 and pat2.PatternLength > pat1.PatternLength
WHERE pat2.Pattern IS NULL
```

So, some example text:

> Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 3:27 PM Central

This should return '2/1/2022 3:27 PM' which you should be able to convert to a DATETIME. I did not bother with the Central. Every example you showed included Central, so you can probably just assume it is Central time.

Comment: This worked great for pulling the date.  thank you.  I didn't list my whole problem.  I guess I wasn't thinking of it correctly.  To add to your solution. Here is the phrase I am trying to extract date/time from:  Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 3:27 PM Central.  When I try to pull out time I can't convert it to a time.  I'm not sure who the converts are failing.  I didn't tell say this correctly in my original post that there would be an "at" between the date and time.  Can someone help me with the above solution to modify it to work with retrieving date/time.

Comment: @AshaRichardson How about this: add a timestamp field. Basically, add a new field like {callTimeStamp datetime not null default(current_timestamp)} which will automatically include the exact time the record is added. Will that be a good enough timestamp? Or do you need the timestamp from the user's notes? Because users can have typos. They can fat-finger a date and wind up with 20222 or mistype the date completely. But, a system-generated timestamp that marks exactly when the record enters the system will always be in the prescribed format.

Comment: I need the timestamp from the field which is not the timestamp it was entered.  i appreciate where you're going with that.  Is there someway to be able to convert to datetime, but return a NULL if it doesn't convert instead of providing an error?  I was able to get the time our, but when I converted it errored on a record that couldn't convert.  I'm assuming they entered the time in wrong.

Comment: Definitely. If it cannot find a pattern match, then it should not try to convert the substring. Add an IIF check to see if the pattern is null. If it is, that means no matching pattern was found.

Comment: Your code is genius for me... but.. I'm a little stuck and out of my wheel house.

Comment: I updated my answer already.

Comment: Did you see where I pasted a sample of my data?  I need to pull date and time. 
 How do you recommend I do that?  Physician/Physician’s office called on 6/9/2021 at 2:55 PM Central.[code]
Physician/Physician’s office called on 6/9/2021 at 2:55 PM Central.
Physician/Physician’s office called on 6/9/2021 at 4:35 PM Central.
Physician/Physician’s office called on 8/18/2020 at 4:29 PM Central.
Physician/Physician’s office called on 8/18/2020 at 3:12 PM Central.
Physician/Physician’s office called on 8/18/2020 at 2:08 PM Central.[/code]

Comment: I updated my answer to include pulling time.

Comment: I modified my query to your example and I got this error message.  I had to remove UCASE because it says it's not supported.  I changed the at to a lowercase at which is only way it is spelled in the data.    Msg 8152, Level 16, State 30, Line 60
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I modified my query to your example and I got this error message.  I had to remove UCASE because it says it's not supported.  I changed the at to a lowercase at which is only way it is spelled in the data.    Msg 8152, Level 16, State 30, Line 60
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I can pull the time out, but the problem is this is a text field where users are entering the date/time and I think there is inconsistent formats.  When I try either example, I am getting errors.  Is there a way I can ignore conversion errors for whatever rows fail to convert?

Comment: I got your query running, but it's not matching on anything now.  Do you have any ideas on how I tweak it?

Comment: Can you repost your orginal solution that pulled the date only?

Comment: @AshaRichardson Oops! I have been working with old vbscript and they use the UCASE function for upper case. the ' at ' is not the reason for forcing upper case. it is to match the pattern with AM and PM. If the AM and PM are always upper case and the ' at ' is always lower case, then you don't need that. Anyway, I added a check to verify that the length of the string is long enough to satisfy the conditions of substring.

Comment: @AshaRichardson You can see the original solution by clicking the little back in time symbol under the mark up and mark down votes for the answer. Once you click that time symbol,  everywhere that it says "history edited" under the "what" column, there is a right arrow. Click that to see what changed.

Comment: @AshaRichardson Your sample data was very useful. I fixed the SQL and it runs against your sample data now.

Comment: You've been so very helpful!  thank you for helping me.  your solution worked for me! I've been trying to add the @slipeternal to address you, but I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: I have been getting notified. I think you are doing it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I got a little more information about this post from another thread including a hint of what the data actually looks like.  Here's the same code part of the response I created including the test data if someone else wants to play.

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable;
GO
--===== Create and populate the test table from the data provided.
     -- This is NOT a part of the solution. We're just creating test data here.
 SELECT *
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM (VALUES
         ('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 3:27 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 3:34 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 2:47 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 4:17 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 2:52 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 2:51 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 4:17 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 4:34 PM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 11:49 PM Eastern.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 11:27 AM Eastern.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 11:34 AM Eastern.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 10:47 AM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 9:17 AM Mountain.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 10:52 AM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 10:51 AM Central.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 9:17 AM Pacific.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 9:34 AM Pacific.')
        ,('Physician/Physician’s office called on 2/1/2022 at 11:49 AM Somewhere over the rainbow.')
        )v(SomeString)
;
--===== Let's see what we've got
 SELECT * FROM #TestTable
;
--===== Solve the given problem.
     -- So long as the following pattern is true in the source data, this should always work.
     --     WhoCalled by the string ' called on ' to determine the caller followed by...
     --     by a date string followed by the string ' at ' followed by a meridian time (Has AM/PM) for the CallDT followed by...
     --     a time zone name string for the TimeZone.
     -- The result is available as a DATETIME2(0) with no decimal seconds.
 SELECT SomeString
        ,WhoCalled  = LEFT(SomeString,ca1.CalledOn-1)
        ,CallDT     = CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SomeString,ca1.CalledOn+10,ca2.Meridian-CalledOn-9),'at',''))
        ,TimeZone   = TRIM(' .' FROM SUBSTRING(SomeString,ca2.Meridian+2,500))  
   FROM #TestTable
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' called on ',SomeString)))ca1(CalledOn)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('% [AP]M %',SomeString)+2))ca2(Meridian)
;
GO
```

Comment: I tried to get this to work, but there are syntax errors and I can't figure out where to fix the syntax errors.

Comment: I tried to get this to work, but there are syntax errors and I can't figure out where to fix the syntax errors.  I'm not understanding how the ca1.Calledon and ca2.Meridan gives you staring positions.  Is that why I am erroring out?

Comment: I don't know because I don't have the code that you're executing.  Could you add it to your original question?  Then, I (and the others) can have a look.